# iam begineeer to the swift.i have created the table view when xml parsing is done .its showing me only height of the cell.blank cells

Tags: swift, xml, uitableview

I am new to the Swift language and just a beginner, I have created tableview. I want to show the data whereas when I'm running the code it shows me empty cells. I have checked the delegates and connections .

```
func numberOfSections(in dashboardtable: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 114
}

func tableView(_ dashboardtable: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return toddler.count
}

func tableView(_ dashboardtable: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = dashboardtable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DashTableViewCell

    cell.cname.text = toddler[indexPath.row]["ChildName"] as? String
    cell.cage.text = toddler[indexPath.row]["Age"] as? String
    cell.childc.text = toddler[indexPath.row]["Class"] as? String
    if let base64 = toddler[indexPath.row]["Photo"] as? String,let data = Data.init(base64Encoded: base64), let image = UIImage.init(data: data){
        cell.childimage.image = image
    } else {
        cell.childimage.image = UIImage.init(named: "")
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    //to display the whole details
    print(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: are you reloading the tableView after the toddler dictionary gets filled? also check the tableview's datasource, because it is responsible for the cellForRow at method which shows the data

Comment: Please explain more for better understand.

Comment: I am just using the service ,based on the  xml parsing service I am getting the data.in my tableview i have one image and three labels to be filled by the backend data. yes i am reloading the data.when i am running the code i am getting blank data

Answer (score 0):

If you want hide lines in blank tableView

use this:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

be sure set delegate and datasource and call reloadData

Comment: my question was i have added the image and some labels in the tableview when im running the code the data is nt showing me, it shows only the blank cells.the data is in the array format

Comment: Firstly remove tableView in interface and remove from code. After that add tableView in intarface and set the constraints. Connect the outlet. and write this

tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

After that code, it's must be work

Comment: HI every one.i have an table view. the table view contains date and shift timings.i have an searchbar. based on time and shift how can i search the data.

Comment: You can use filter function in array

Comment: hi i have an filtred array. im using searchbar delegate asa well in the  textdid change what do i implement

Comment: You have to 2 array, first one is original data ( full data ) second one is filtered data, you should tableView datasource has filtered data. If searchbar text is nil or empty you set filtered data equal to original data.

Comment: Hi i have an doubt ..how can i call the service inside the service uisng soapservices.

Comment: You can find how can you request soap service, google it pls

Comment: In my table view cell i have date. iam having searchbar in the tableview.now the requirement is based on the date i want to search the details of the employee.and i have done with searching name.its working fine.i also want to search the with the date. the date format is "MM/dd/YYYY". can any one help.based on the date the i want to search the details.and the date is coming from the webservice.